# Gaining access to Lemonstand configuration tool

Tags: php

I'm working on a Lemonstand-based site that I've been provided the code and mysql database for, but unfortunately I cannot seem to configure the mysql login details in my working copy of the site without gaining access to the Lemonstand configuration tool. The client cannot remember their login details for this and they do not seem to match the login details they use for administering the site on a daily basis, so I was wondering if there is either:

- A way to reset the configuration tool login details?
- A different way to set up the mysql connection configuration variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please submit a support ticket to LemonStand. We will help you to reset the settings and access the Configuration Tool.

Comment: Or, you could have commented here helping other people stranded on lemonstand.